# Laravel 4, Multiples conditions in Having

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In laravel 4, I have a query that should load users near to you (by distance)

1- I should load users close to you if distance<5km and user_type='user'
2- and load all users if distance<20km and user_type="admin"

I did this query, like how we do in where, but it doesn't work

```
->having(function ($query) use ($distance) {
        $query->having('distance',"<", $distance)
              ->having('user_role',"=", 'user');
})
->orHaving(function ($query) use ($distance_admin) {
        $query->having('distance',"<", $distance_admin)
              ->having('user_role',"=", 'admin');
})
```

I calculate distance with DB::raw()

You can help me please

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you would convert it to sql (laravel has a method that does that) and see where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution with using havingRaw(), I put the condition on it directly